# Bibtex author name - unusual use case

Tags: bibtex

I need to cite a paper whose author apparently wishes to be known as `"A.James Hancock"` (I changed the actual name). How do I get the `abbrv` style to produce that? I keep getting `A.Hancock`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please, add also the entry in the `.bib` file.

Comment: This works, but the sorting :-) -- `author="{\mbox{A.James Hancock}}",` However I recommend biblatex with the style `numeric`.

Comment: I went for the mbox solution, together with a noopsort I added. Thanks all!!

Comment: There's no need for `\mbox` skullduggery. Since you're looking to reproduce the full middle name even though you're using the `abbrv` bibliography style, you might as well set the author field to `name = {James Hancock, Andrew}` (or whatever else `A` should expand to). Basically, you'd be tricking BibTeX into treating "James Hancock" as the surname and "Andrew" as the first name; the "first name" will get abbreviated to `A.` by the `abbrv` style file.

Answer (score 4):

If you're willing to switch to [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex), here's how to disable its `firstinits` option for a single entry. (Note that `style=numeric,firstinits=true` is the `biblatex` equivalent to `abbrv.bst`.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=numeric,firstinits=true]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{Han12,
  execute = {\togglefalse{blx@firstinits}},
  author = {Hancock, A. James},
  year = {2012},
  title = {An unusual use case},
}
@book{Lam85,
  author = {Lamport, Leslie},
  year = {1985},
  title = {\LaTeX: A document preparation system},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The `abbrv` style abbreviates names, as its name implies, so it's indifferent what name the author wants to be used.

With

```
@article{key,
author={Hancock, A. James},
title={Title},
journal={Journal},
year=2000,
}
```

the entry in the bibliography would be

> [1] A. J. Hancock. Title. *Journal*, 2000.

You're probably inputting `A.James` without a space, so the abbreviated form *will* be "A.", as for BibTeX there is only one (peculiar) first name.

With the `plain` bibliography style you would get, from the same entry,

> [1] A. James Hancock. Title. *Journal*, 2000.